# First page Look Fine but giving wrong results in next pages Laravel vue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I am facing issue in laravel pagination. First page of record is showing exactly that I am looking for but giving the wrong results in second or next pages.
I don't know what i am doing wrong.. I also checked the json data not getting the exactly result according to the search query.

```
        $lawcase =DB::table('cases');
    if($request->cases_ids){
        $lawcase=$lawcase->whereIn('id1',$request->cases_ids);
    }
    /***********Case Law Search *********/
    if($request->case_keyword){
        $lawcase=$lawcase->where('detail3','like','%'.$request->case_keyword.'%');
    }
    /******Citation Search End*******/
    $lawcase=orderBy('id1','desc')->paginate(30);
    return response()->json(['lawcase'=>$lawcase,'search_count'=>$lawcase->total()], 200);
```

In Vue js (Frontend)

```
  <nav class="navigation pagination">
        <div class="nav-links">
            <paginate :page-count="lastpage" :click-handler="getPageRecord" :prev-text="'Prev'" :next-text="'Next'">
            </paginate>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is the page record:

```
        getPageRecord(pageNum) {
            $('#preloader').modal('show')
            axios.get('/cases/getCase?page=' + pageNum).then(response => {
                this.casesList = response.data.lawcase.data;
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 300 }, "slow");
                $('#preloader').modal('hide')
            })
        }
```

Comment: Lets see your `getPageRecord` vuejs method

Comment: @tsommie getpageRecord added

Comment: A lot is happening in your code, some of it I don't agree with. try using https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination, and then move your `ifs` and `wheres` to a local scope and then making a query like `$lawcase->search()->paginate()`.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue on vue side because I am not getting corrects records from laravel side.

Comment: True, but what if the first request is fine but not the subsequent ones then its possible the second request going out to laravel is wrong.